# Compare values of DataFrames and write to new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, compare

i am pretty new to coding in general and might need some help.
To my problem: I have 2 DataFrames, which do have different lengths:

| df1 | df2 |
| --- | --- |
| AB | AB |
| AC | AC |
| AD | NaN |
| AF | NaN |
| ... | ... |

Now I want to compare those two dataframe values and create a new dataframe containing only the values from df1 without the ones from df2.
So in the end it should look like this:

| df3 |
| --- |
| AD |
| AF |
| ... |
| ... |

I have tried the following solutions but they did not give the right output.
`df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)`
as well as
 `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left')`
I feel like the solution is not that hard but until now I wasn't able to figure this out.
Maybe someone can helf me figure out how to do this.
Thank you in advance!!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AF']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['AB', 'AC', np.nan, np.nan]})
df1.loc[~df1.col.isin(df2.col)]
```

Output:

```
    col
2   AD
3   AF
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. when i try this it throws the error "TypeError: unhashable type: DataFrame"

Comment: Is your dataset like mine? what is the name of your column?

Comment: can you print your dataframe?

Comment: I transformed 2 lists into the dataframes so the Dataframes do not have column names. I have tried to add a column name but it throws the same error

Comment: Hi I found a solution :) ```df1[~df1.apply(tuple,1).isin(df2.apply(tuple,1)```

Comment: If your columns don't have name you can get them using `df[0]`. so change my code to `df1.loc[~df1[0].isin(df2[0])]`.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to change them into tuple like what you're doing because it works here but not in general when you have more columns than 1.